# How to convert XML into formated text file whith XSlt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file which is looks like:

```
<Report>
<Total>
    <RecordValues>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="1" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="100" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="tester" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-10-18 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Menu" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission X" />
        </Record>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="2" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="100" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="user1" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-12-15 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Control" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission E" />
        </Record>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="3" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="15" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="user2" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-10-02 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Run" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission R" />
        </Record>
    </RecordValues>
</Total>
```

I have to convert it with XSLT into formated text file:

```
1 100  101810
tester  Menu       Permission X
2 100  121510
user1   Control    Permission E
3 15   100210
user2   Run        Permission R
```

The only **fieldValue** attribute must be used and all fields in the text file have fixed length. 
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1 or can you use XSLT 2?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think its 1.

Comment: @user529642: Unless there is some parametrization or twice the number of field, if field width are fixed it means that paddings are fixed and you could do it manualy faster.

Comment: I cannot do this manually because it has to be part of the batch process, and real file much more bigger.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what output did it produce? in what way did it not work?

Comment: What is the fixed length for each field? Also, what determines a field? For instance, if you have a field for @fieldValue for fieldName="index", your example shows a max of two characters. If your real file is so much bigger, it's possible that your index has more than two characters.

Comment: The output file is determined by required file layout.

Comment: It has two type of records and each field has fixed length. Its just an example with the same structure as a real file.

Comment: This task came out yesterday, and I have very limited knowledge in XSLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:m="map">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vPadding"
         select="'             &#xA;                               '"/>
    <m:m n="index" p="1"/>
    <m:m n="version" p="3"/>
    <m:m n="user" p="15"/>
    <m:m n="date_modified" p="8"/>
    <m:m n="object_name" p="23"/>
    <m:m n="permission" p="34"/>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FieldValue">
        <xsl:param name="pOutput" select="$vPadding"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vValue">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@fieldValue"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vPos"
                      select="document('')/*/m:m
                                 [@n=current()/@fieldName]/@p"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vOutput"
             select="concat(substring($pOutput,1,$vPos -1),
                            $vValue,
                            substring($pOutput,$vPos+string-length($vValue)))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext">
            <xsl:with-param name="pOutput" select="$vOutput"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:if test="not($vNext)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vOutput,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[../@fieldName='date_modified']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(translate(.,'-',''),5,4),
                                     substring(.,3,2))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
1 100  101810
tester  Menu       Permission X
2 100  121510
user1   Control    Permission E
3 15   100210
user2   Run        Permission R
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal, a padding mask, inline map with value starting position.

**EDIT**: Strip space just in case...

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro, I tested your solution. Its produced correct result. The only problem I see here is that the first line doesn't started from the beginning of the file and there is an empty line after every two records. This file should well formatted.
Here is the result:

```
        1 100  101810
tester  Menu       Permission X

        2 100  121510
user1   Control    Permission E

        3 15   100210
user2   Run        Permission R
```

Thanks again for your respond.